# How to list all table columns in sorted order on Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, table

I know that `\d table_name` lists all columns for that table, but is there a way to list them sorted in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Generally, use the `information_schema`:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'public' 
AND table_name = 'blah' 
ORDER BY column_name ASC;
```

Comment: Works perfect. Great answer!

Comment: If you realize you actually wanted them in the order they appear in the table,`ORDER BY ordinal_position` gets you pretty close (it's the order they were in at table creation).

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
SELECT col_attr.attname as "ColumnName" 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute col_attr 
WHERE col_attr.attnum > 0 
AND NOT col_attr.attisdropped 
AND col_attr.attrelid = 
(SELECT cls.oid 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class cls 
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ns 
ON ns.oid = cls.relnamespace 
WHERE cls.relname = 'MyTable') 
ORDER BY "ColumnName" ASC
```

Comment: Could you explain that query?, seems a little confusing to me.

Comment: @Oxfist you can find the column level description of these tables at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/catalogs.html

Comment: Will do. Thank you. The previous answer was clearer, though.